# Como pegar uma variável dentro de método de uma outra classe

Tags: java

Boa noite, to começando a aprender Java e me deparei com esse problema e preciso de ajuda.
Quero chamar uma variável para minha Main, só que ela tá dentro de um método.
Eu já tentei usar player.spawn(), mas isso só serve se o método estiver retornando algo, e não é bem isso que eu quero.

**Main:**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao jogo!");
    System.out.println("Pressione qualquer tecla para começar");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String start = in.nextLine();
    
    Player player = new Player();
    player.spawn();
    
    while(vivo)//variável que eu quero chamar
    {
        System.out.println("It just works");
    }
}
```

**Player:**

```
public class Player {

           public void spawn()
       {
           System.out.println("Jogador spawnado");
           boolean vivo = true;
           int vida = 3;
           int dano = 1;
           int defesa = 1;
           }
```

}

Comment: coloque o metodo spawn como Static

Comment: Eu coloquei, só que continua dando o mesmo problema :/

Comment: E outra coisa que esqueci de mencionar, coloque as variaveis FORA do método (ou seja, no escopo da classe), quando quiser acessar as variavéis dentro do método, use o THIS  ou através de Getter/Setter

Answer (score 1):

A maneira correta seria você criar um método getter, para poder acessar o valor vivo, de dentro da classe Player.

Segue um exemplo:

***Player.java***

```
public class Player {
       private boolean vivo;
       public Player() {
             vivo = true;
       }
       public void spawn(){
           System.out.println("Jogador spawnado");
           int vida = 3;
           int dano = 1;
           int defesa = 1;
       }
       public boolean getVivo() {
          return vivo;
       }
}
```

Depois em sua classe `main.java`, basta chamar o método `getVivo()`:

```
while(player.getVivo())//variável que eu quero chamar
{
    System.out.println("It just works");
}
```

Repare que em minha solução fizemos os seguintes passos:

1. colocamos a variável vivo como uma variável de instância da classe Player.
2. Adicionamos um método construtor apenas para iniciar o valor da variável vivo. (poderíamos criar (mais de um construtor para por exemplo ter um que aceita parâmetros, para instânciar a nossa classe de uma maneira mais adaptável)
3. Adicionamos um `getter` para o valor da variável vivo.
4. Em nosso método main utilizamos o método `getVivo()`

Observe que desta estamos quebrando alguns princípios da programação orientação a objetos utilizando nossa classe desta forma, uma delas é o encapsulamento.

Se não quisermos quebrar o encapsulamento devemos ter um getter e um setter para cada atributo da nossa classe. Uma versão mais orientado a objeto de nossa classe seria:

***Player.java***

```
public class Player {
   private boolean vivo;
   private int vida;
   private int dano;
   private int defesa;

   public Player() {
   //construtor padrão
   }
   public Player(boolean vivo, int vida, int dano, int defesa) {
      this.vivo = vivo;
      this.vida = vida;
      this.dano = dano;
      this.defesa = defesa;
      System.out.println("Jogador spawnado");
   }
   
  public boolean getVivo() {
      return vivo;
  }
  public int getVida() {
      return vida;
  }
  public int getDano() {
      return dano;
  }
  public int getDefesa() {
      return defesa;
  }
  public void setVivo(boolean vivo){
      this.vivo = vivo;
  }
  public void setVida(int vida) {
      this.vida = vida;
  }
  public void setDano(int dano) {
       this.dano = dano;
  }
  public void setDefesa(int defesa) {
       this.defesa = defesa;
  }
}
```

Depois em seu `main.java` basta chamar o construtor da classe player com os valores para instanciar sua classe.

***Main.java***

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao jogo!");
    System.out.println("Pressione qualquer tecla para começar");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String start = in.nextLine();
    
    //aqui usamos os valores que estavam dentro do método spawn()
    Player player = new Player(true, 3, 1, 1);
    //player.spawn(); -->não é mais necessário pois estamos utilizando o construtor
    
    while(player.getVivo())//variável que eu quero chamar
    {
        System.out.println("It just works");
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu trocaria o `getVivo()` por `isVivo()` para manter a convenção de nomenclatura do `getter` em `boolean`. Caso fosse um `Boolean` a convenção `getVivo()` estaria correta.